# Shall we call the destroy() method from the init() and service() methods in Servlet?

Tags: servlets, lifecycle

Shall we call the `destroy()` method from the `init()` and `service()` methods in a Servlet? I got many confusing answers across the blogs.

As I understand it, when we call the `destroy()` method from the `init()` it should call and destroy the servlet, if we are going to override the `destroy()` in our servlet. Then the servlet will get destroyed.

Is the above understanding right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

None of all is true.

The servlet's `destroy()` method is only called by the container whenever it's going to be shutdown. During container's shutdown all servlets will be destroyed. You should not call the method yourself. The `destroy()` method just offers you the opportunity to execute some code upon shutdown. For example, to close some external resources which were opened during `init()`.

E.g.

```
private SomeExternalResource someExternalResource;

@Override 
public void init() {
    someExternalResource = new SomeExternalResource();
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    someExternalResource.close();
}
```

You do not necessarily need to implement the method when you have nothing to clean up.

Comment: That is the ideal scenario with respect to the servlet life cycle. If by mistake i will call the destroy method from service then what happen

Comment: Well, then the code in that method will be executed the usual Java way as every other method. The servlet won't be destroyed or something. The container is the only who does that **after** it has called the `destroy()` method during shutdown.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the confirmation

Answer (score 0):

In java servlet, the `destroy()` method is not supposed to be called by the programmer. But, if it is invoked, it gets executed. But the main question is, will the servlet get destroyed? No, it will not. `destroy()` method will not destroy a java servlet. It is just the method(we can say as an event) get called when web container is going to destroy the servlet for any of the reason (like server restart).

But if you invoke the `destroy()` method yourself, the content just gets executed and then the respective process continues. With respective to this question, the `destroy()` gets executed and then the servlet initialization gets completed.